# CSS Active link not working

Tags: html, css

So I have a nav bar. Built using Zurb:

```
<div class="seven columns navigation" id="navigation">
    <a href="#">Page1</a>
    <a href="#">Page2</a>
    <a href="#">Page3</a>
    <a href="#">Page4</a>
    <a href="#">Page5</a>
 </div>
```

On hover the navigation changes the background color. Thats simple. However I can not get the background to stay if the link is active. So if your on page1 it stays with a blue background.

Here is the CSS i have tried so far.

```
.navigation a {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  color: #666666;
  font-weight: bold; }

.navigation a:hover{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }

.navigation a.active{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }

#navigation a .active-link{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }
```

Non of it works, I have googled this loads, but it all says active-link should work?

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Sorry if its simple CSS isn't my strongest language.

EDIT:

Thanks for the suggestions, however

```
.navigation a:active{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px; }
```

doesn't work either.

Comment: It would help if the active styles differed from the hover styles. That way you would actually see it working.

Comment: Your website unless it has a server side language has no understanding of what page it's on and can't go 'Well I'm page 7 so i'll make Page7.html link as active.]

Comment: Using class names like '.active' is going to cause you headaches. `a` element pseudos are: `:link, :hover, :visited, :active, :focus`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I saw that there's an error here, as it should be `:active` and not `.active`, so replace:

```css
.navigation a.active {
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

With:

```css
.navigation a:active {
  background: #29abe2;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  color: #fff;
}
```

---

Else, if you are talking about each page having an active state, then what CSS you have written is correct. In your HTML, you need to add this:

```css
<div class="seven columns navigation" id="navigation">
  <a href="#" class="active">Page1</a>
  <a href="#">Page2</a>
  <a href="#">Page3</a>
  <a href="#">Page4</a>
  <a href="#">Page5</a>
</div>
```

Now, that particular link will be displayed in the active state. It has to be done for each page, if you are using HTML, or it can be done using programming if you are using something like PHP. So, the same thing in PHP would be:

```css
<div class="seven columns navigation" id="navigation">
  <a href="#"<?php if ($page == 1) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>Page1</a>
  <a href="#"<?php if ($page == 2) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>Page2</a>
  <a href="#"<?php if ($page == 3) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>Page3</a>
  <a href="#"<?php if ($page == 4) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>Page4</a>
  <a href="#"<?php if ($page == 5) echo ' class="active"'; ?>>Page5</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work, I'm even more confused now, hover works and copied your example exactly, no joy. :/

Comment: Can you provide us a fiddle?

Comment: I will try to set one up and get back to you. :)

Comment: tabbing to something triggers `:focus` not `:active`

Comment: @Dawson What is `:active` state then? I am willing to correct and update my answer. :)

Comment: @Dawson I have removed the incorrect information. Can you please remove the downvote?

Comment: `:active` = `mousedown` (simply put). Don't apply ANY CSS to your links, and most browsers will flash red text for active, purple for visited, and blue for link. `:focus` will give you the dotted outline.

Comment: So it is NOT that `:active` should be `.active`, it's that you were apparently unaware of the pseudo `:active`, and the OP is using poorly chosen class names.

Comment: @Dawson I have removed the incorrect text itself. And also, I understood that the OP wants different active states for the different pages. Have I done it correctly?

Comment: Technically, Yes. But I still have issue that the Up Voted answers do not address the fact of POOR naming convention on the OP's part. `.active` is valid...but it's a sh*tty name for a class - especially sh*tty for a class intended for `<a>` elements. I removed my down vote. but I think the OP is getting the quickie fixes, and not going to chose better nomenclatures moving forward.

Comment: @Dawson Er... I guess, even I *might* name that way, but what is the best naming you would suggest?

Comment: I try to name things relative/unique to functionality. In OP's case, "This nav item matches the page/URL I'm currently viewing", so I'd use something like: `a.current-url, a.current, or a.viewing`

Comment: Yeah, `.current` is the one I use... :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't quite do what you want to do with pure CSS.  First, you have to define the class to use for a link when the user is on that page (like you did, but you have a typo):

```
.navigation a.active-link {
      background: #29abe2;
      color: #fff;
      border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Next, you need to apply that class to the link when the user visits that page.  So, if I'm on Page 1, the navigation would look like this:

```
<div class="seven columns navigation" id="navigation">
    <a href="#" class="active-link">Page1</a>
    <a href="#">Page2</a>
    <a href="#">Page3</a>
    <a href="#">Page4</a>
    <a href="#">Page5</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Doesn't `a .active-link` target a child of `<a>` with a class of `active-link`?

Comment: Ah, thanks for that.  There were two typos in that line and I forgot to fix that one.  Edited to reflect the right code.

Answer (score 2):

`a:visited` is actually your '.active' state. For the effect that was causing you to wonder what was going on.

You've got to include it in your `a:` pseudo classes if you're going to try and utilize it that way.

Establishing a "default/reset" state for your `<a>` elements will prevent this type of "WTF?" scenarios:

```
a:link { color:black }
a:hover { color:blue }
a:visited, a:active, a:focus { color:red }
```

When you want a particular link to show "highlighted" on its corresponding page, you're best off to use an ID or Class (depending on your usage):

```
<a id="highlight">Home</a>
<a>About</a>
<a>Contact</a>
```

**EDIT**

Reread your question again. `#navigation a .active-link{...` isn't working for you because of the space between `a` and `.active-link`. You're actually targeting a child of `a` with the class name of `active-link`. Fix #1 would be `a.active-link`.

Disregard what you're reading above about PHP, Targeter, etc. It seems that you're just trying to make your navigation 'highlight'/change for just the page that matches the link in the nav. You can easily do this with straight HTML/CSS (if you have problems with this, server-side code solutions will just frustrate you more). See the three `<a>` elements in my answer. Then add this to your CSS (Fix #2):

```
a#highlight { color:red }
```

I believe that your snafu is all a product of using class names that are too close to 'reserved' names in CSS (so you missed a.active vs a:active -- even though both ARE VALID, they're easy to miss when you're proofreading your code). (Fix #3)

Answer (score 2):

To solve that with just CSS tricks you'll need to use the Selector Target, first you attribute different id for the pages and put the link to that reference, then you change the style base on the ID that is being target.

Here is the [JS Fiddle of the Solution with just CSS and HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/hRxr2/1/)

But essentially it works like this:

Here is your HTML with the id and target changes

```
<div class="seven columns navigation" id="navigation">
    <a href="#page1" id="page1">Page1</a>
    <a href="#page2" id="page2">Page2</a>
    <a href="#page3" id="page3">Page3</a>
    <a href="#page4" id="page4">Page4</a>
    <a href="#page5" id="page5">Page5</a>
</div>
```

And after all that css you need to change the style based on the target like so:

```
#page1:target, #page2:target, #page3:target, #page4:target, #page5:target{
  background: #29abe2;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

This works, but the usual is to use a server side, such as ruby on rails, python, php, whatever language you feel confortable that will provide the exact url and that use a simple jQuery [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) or [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) or even [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to put the active class on the right link.

Hope It Helps!
Cheers

Comment: Sorry because I know this is really, really old, but I can't see active as doing anything. I played with your jsfiddle and removed the css pertaining to it and can't tell that anything is different. What are a.active and a .active-link for? http://jsfiddle.net/hRxr2/605/

Comment: Hi, late response! I guess the .active and .actve-link didn't do anything really :). The trick here was using `:target` css-selector to activate a style rather than using javascript to modify the dom.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use in jQuery for browser compatibility

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    var urlArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
    var pagAtual =urlArray[urlArray.length -1];
    $("a[href*="+pagAtual+"]").css("color","#67E8A7");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an active class and then assign that to the links in the navbar manually.

HTML + CSS have no understanding of where they are and can't go

> "Well I'm on article.html so i'll make the article link active."

So you need to either use javascript or some programming language such as python, php, asp etc... to assign a class to the correct link when you are on that page e.g Build the navigation dynamically using a server side language.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace .navigation with #navigation, there is id="navigation",not a class.

Answer (score 0):

In other news, `:action` is also cancelled if you have `event.preventDefault()` on *mousedown* event.

This doesn't apply to *click* and *mouseup* events though, you can use preventDefault() with them without cancelling :action behavior. I didn't tested touch events, but I assume it will be the same case.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, but I solved it the following way, **but some things are weird**:

The **app.component.html** file:

```
    <div class="container">
      <nav class="navbar" >
        <form class="form-inline">
          <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="list">List</a>
          <a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="create" 
             style="padding-left: 20px;">Create</a>
        </form>
      </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
```

The **app.component.css** file:

```
    /* unvisited link */
    a.link {
      color: blue;
    }

    /* selected link */
    a.active {
      color: hotpink;
    }

    /* visited link (This doesn't work well, so I don't use it in my app)*/
    a.visited {
      color: green;
    }

    /* mouse over link */
    a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
```

[image]

**Weird things:**

1. For **active link color**, **"a.active"** works, while **"a:active"** does **NOT** work;
2. For **hover color**, **"a:hover"** works, while **"a.hover"** does **NOT** work.
3. For **visited link color**, if I use **"a:visited"**, other colors will be **disabled**.

There are still other cases, but it'd be too much to talk in details.

It took me a long time to figure it out.

By the way, **routerLinkActive="active"** is necessary. I got rid of it just to test it, and it didn't work. So I put it back, and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I was having problems with changing colors for active links, and realized after way too long that because I was hosting the site locally while testing, some paths were of course not the same, and the corresponding links were not actually active.

Answer (score -1):

I just found a solution for this `elementor-button` that now works on the active state.

Instead of using the class `elementor-button`, you need to target the class `elementor-button-link` e.g., `.elementor-button-link:active{add styles here...}`.

If your button has no link in it, then you can use the `elementor-button` class but instead of Active, you need to use Focus.
It works!