# Navigation links text color 1 color at a time

Tags: html, css

I have 5 navigation links.  I want them to always remain a black text color.  When a user clicks on a link, I want it to become a different color.  When they go to another link, I want the previous link to become black again, but the current one to change again.  Basically, 4 links will always be black, but the current one is different, but I need the previous link to change to black.  Right now after a user visits all of my links, they will all become a different color, and black is not seen again until cookies are erased.  An example is here- https://www.apple.com .  Apple's navigation links are all white, but when you visit a link, it changes to a grey, then when you go to another link, the link you were just on changes back to white and your current link is grey.  Thank you for those that help.  Below is my HTML & CSS:

```
<nav>
<a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
<a href="about.html">About</a> &nbsp;
<a href="services.html">Services</a> &nbsp;
<a href="sales.html">For Sale</a> &nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a> &nbsp;
</nav>

nav a { text-decoration: none; }

nav a:link { color: #000000; }

nav a:visited { color: #333333; }

nav a:hover { color: #333333; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I thought at first glance is that you were looking for the active link. That is, the link that is currently being utilized will be the different color. Simple add this to your css and make it whatever color you need.

```
/* selected link */
nav a:active {
    color: blue;
}
```

What that does, however, is only change the link while it's being clicked. In order to do what you need is a little more complicated. This has been covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898015/css-active-link-not-working).

Essentially you have to set up an active class in your css that you can call in your html from the current page.

```
.navigation a.active {
      color: #333;
}
```

And your html:

```
<div class="navigation" id="navigation">
    <a href="#" class="active">Page1</a>
    <a href="#">Page2</a>
    <a href="#">Page3</a>
    <a href="#">Page4</a>
    <a href="#">Page5</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do I need to get rid of my nav a:visited?

Comment: No, just change that back to black.

Comment: Half-way there now.  The problem is that it does not stay #333333, but stays black for all links.  I just need the current link to remain different.     nav a:link { color: #000000; }

nav a:visited { color: #000000; }

nav a:hover { color: #333333; }

nav a:active { color: #333333; }

Comment: You know, I apologize. The active link only changes while it's being clicked. I'm editing my answer to provide more info.

Comment: No problem at all.

Comment: Where did you get your <div class="navigation" id="navigation">?

Comment: It is actually working.  I do have to put the class="active" just once in every link for that link, correct?

Comment: It's just another way of doing it in place of your <nav> up there. That way you can set it all in css. You could probably just set up the .active class. That's the main thing you have to do. You will put the class="active" on the  navlink for each page. So when you're on the index page, the index link will have the active class. When you're on the about page, the about link will have it. And so on.

Comment: Awesome.  You really helped and made my page look better.  Is it OK to have this-                                                                                                   <div class="navigation" id="navigation">
<nav>
<a href="index.html">Home</a> &nbsp;
<a href="about.html">About</a> &nbsp;
<a href="services.html" class="active">Services</a> &nbsp;
<a href="sales.html">For Sale</a> &nbsp;
<a href="contact.html">Contact</a> &nbsp;
</nav>
</div>

Comment: Can you tell me where you got id="navigation"?  I thought id's have '#' in CSS?

Comment: You can have both classes and id's. IDs are used for one element, where classes can do multiple elements. I was just using it as an example.

Comment: Would it be OK to delete the ID from the <div class="navigation" id="navigation">?

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but I'm just trying to learn this.  Your code for .navigation a.active { color: #333; }- Is this a class in a class basically?

Comment: Basically you can group selectors in order to save space. For example h1, h2, p {
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
}

Comment: I will check it out.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the a:visited attribute to: `{color: #000000}`.

Comment: Good looking out. I forgot to mention that part.

Comment: I do want the color to become #333333 for the current page they are on.